# UIpicker scrolling sound

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uipickerview

I getting mad doing the research for the solution of this method. I want to control or disable the clicking sound whenever the picker is scrolled. now i want to use the documented one. Can you help me solve this at the range of 1 day? please I really need to do this as fast as i could. But I guess you can give me some hint to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
[thePickerView setSoundsEnabled:NO];
```

There's no documented way to do this.